# mysql use wildcard in request involving timestamp

Tags: mysql

im trying to select all the rows having a particular year in mysql.
the datetime is in a format such as `2016-12-02 10:00:00` so i am trying to use wildcard to do it. However i tried

```
SELECT * FROM all-data.prices where YEAR(timestamp)= "2005";
```

and `SELECT * FROM all-data.prices where timestamp= "2005%" ;`
and it didnt work for me.

Any suggestion on which is the correct syntax for such select statement?

Comment: Do you have a real `timestamp` column, or is it a `varchar`?

Comment: @Mureinik - no its a real timestamp column

Comment: Hmm... using `year` should have worked. Can you share some sample data and the result you're getting for it?

Comment: here a line of the table:
`8449 2005-01-01 09:00:00 UK 1 Average Earnings ex Bonus 3.90  3.80 `


the error message is `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'all-data.prices where YEAR(timestamp)= "2005"' at line 1`

Answer (score 2):

It is not the best idea to use a FUNCTION on a field in the WHERE Clause. Then MySQL must calculate YEAR(timestamp) from every ROW before it can compare. So it is a FULL TABLE SCAN and cant use a INDEX.

A better was is to compare the timestamp with a Range

```
SELECT * from your_table WHERE `timestamp` >= '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND `timestamp` < '2016-01-01 00:00:00';
```

Then MySQL can use a INDEX (if there is one)

To use % you also must use the LIKE Keyword

```
SELECT '2015-01-01 23:50:00' LIKE '2015%';
```

in your sample

```
 SELECT * from your_table WHERE `timestamp` LIKE '2015%';
```